# JFreeChart XYPlot XYImageAnnotation mouse click listener

Tags: java, click, listener, jfreechart

I have a `JFreeChart` with 2 subplots (XYPlot).

I have `XYImageAnnotation`s that I want to become buttons, but I can't find a way to listen mouse click on any annotation.

[image]

Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried a `ChartMouseListener`?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented this: public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) { 
  MouseEvent me = e.getTrigger();
  if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
   new Thread(){
    public void run(){
     deshacerZoomDominios();
    }
   }.start(); 
  }
 } But I have no idea how to listen click from annotations.

Comment: Look for the `ChartEntity` that's a `XYAnnotationEntity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea how to listen [for] click from annotations

In your `ChartMouseListener`, you'll get a `ChartMouseEvent`. Use it to get the `ChartEntity` that's a `XYAnnotationEntity`.

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
        ChartEntity ce = cme.getEntity();
        if (ce instanceof XYAnnotationEntity) {
            // handle the click
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, look for the `XYItemEntity` to which you added the annotation.

Comment: It works, thank you Catalina Island! Do you know how to check what XYImageAnnotation was clicked if I have several annotations over the graph? Thanks

Comment: @enig: Keep a `List<XYImageAnnotation>` that you can search for a match.

Comment: Thanks both, Be sure that I will check the mark when I get it working. Do you know how to compare XYAnnotationEntity with my List<XYImageAnnotation> in order to get what XYImageAnnotation instance was clicked?

Comment: Finally I iterate through List<XYImageAnnotation> and comparing it URL to the clicked item. The URL contains the array index. Thanks.